# Removing Roof Caulking from Jeans After Roof Job?

Tags: roof, caulking

I'm not exactly sure where to post this question. I've checked a bunch of places on Area 51, and many of the clothing specific StackExchangess have been closed.

I figured that the people most associated with contracting would be most likely be able to help me with this problem, and I suppose that caring for clothing damaged by home improvement activities would (technically?) fall under the home improvement domain as it is part of the clean-up process of home improvement.

Anyway, I got some black roof caulking on my jeans and was wondering if anyone had any tricks for getting it off. It's not a bit deal, but I would prefer to not have it on my jeans if I can get it off. I tried manual abrasion and got a decent amount of it off already, but the remainder is rather resistant to abrasion.[image: Roof Caulking]

This is a picture of the pants after abrasion:
[image: Jeans]

I haven't washed them yet, but I was wondering if anyone had a go-to way to remove it. I'll update the question after I wash them to see if that helped any.

Comment: I don't have experience with that specific sub-product, but from knowing about the other varieties of PL (polyurethane adhesive)... you might be doomed. To get it off your skin, you basically have to shed a layer of skin. If you were feeling brave, you can try acetone (found in some nail polish removers). The internet also suggests "methylene chloride", but I suspect the MSDS sheet on this one is a mile thick.

Comment: You wear old jeans - not your new best ones...

Comment: @SolarMike I did, that doesn't mean that I want a spot on them though :)

Comment: @SarahSzabo that stuff is designed to stick like sh1t to a blanket - otherwise the joints leak... So sticking to jeans is easy...

Comment: Congratulations you now own a pair of work pants.  You do want the spot on there because when you go to grab your work pants you want to make sure you’re putting on your work pants.  One of the benefits of wearing work pants as you have someplace to wipe your hands.

Comment: I use WD-40 for removing any that has gotten on my hands. Works ok for clothing if it hasn't dried but for most clothing, I just give it up as I've not found anything effective in completely removing it.

Comment: I have a sweatshirt that still has polyurethane glue on it from 16 years ago. Just put those jeans on when you are doing the next messy job so you only have one messy pair of jeans, unless you do enough to need two pairs of messy jeans.

Comment: “Life hacks” Stack Exchange is another potential SE for this question.   But I’m afraid the Jeans are now work pants. Hope they weren’t $300 jeans.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up doing stuff like this I had canvas pants for hot tar that could stand up in the corner after a day, chemicals not so good today were used back then to melt the tar and other solvent based adheasives, I mentioned this because it'some of the laytex sealers are tricky and not find 530 love locktight for other things but have have not used in this case. I might look at a latex paint remover to help.

Comment: I was doing roof work once and a guy I was working with told us the quickest way to get tar off our hands was with gasoline.  I was dubious at first but by the end of the work day I was like the scene in Zoolander.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Wow, I wouldn't have thought of that, but you might be onto something.  I remember something similar in one of my chemistry classes. If it's not much better after washing, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Get some odorless paint thinner from local art supplies store. Place a piece of wood on the bench with some old towels/rags to make a working surface. Place the stained area over the towels and wet it with the thinners. Use an old scrub brush to help soften the caulking and scrape with a plastic putty knife. Add as much thinner as needed to remove the caulking.
Then use the brush along the fabric grain to get all the last bits out. Blot all the thinner, then pour on a liquid laundry detergent. Scrub lightly then rinse with warm water, then repeat the detergent step. Rinse one more time, then into the washer.

Comment: Sounds like experience to me, I'll give it a try!